# How to display image thumbnails in a Panorama(or pivot) page and scroll horizontally?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have some Thumbnail images .I want to display image thumbnails in a Panorama(or pivot) page and scroll horizontally as in native windows phone 7 photo viewer application.Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `Orientation` on the `PanoramaItem` to `Horizontal` to recreate the behaviour of the Pictures hub.

The pivot does/should not support horizontal scrolling within an item.

Comment: How do we control how much horizontal scrolling should occur?